# Wamp Server Installation with two Drives and getting Netbeans to Run On Wamp

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp

So I have installed WAMP server initially on my C drive, but I do not want it on my C drive. So I have reinstalled it on my H drive, but some files, looked in (phpinfo), are still pointing in the C drive. Also, how do I get Net beans to work with the Wamp server. I have tried pointing the source file to the www folder under wamp, but it still refuses to connect when i try to run the project. My guess is the files as some files are still pointing in my C drive, in which i believe is suppose to be pointing in the H drive. My two questions are How do I get the Wamp server fully on my H drive, and how do i configure Net beans to work with the server for php web deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The second install of WAMPServer on the H drive will have worked quite happily and should have replaced the install on drive C

So you could delete the installation of drive C:.

If you are still getting things looking at the C drive, then you have probably put a reference to something in your PATH or you have a `my.ini` in the  `C:/windows` folder or subfolders.

WAMPServer does not require you add anything to the PATH. In fact if you do, it will cause you problwms switching versions of PHP/Apache/MYSQL. ALso all it files live inside the `\wamp` and nowhere else